# Count patients for each month

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count patient in each month, and I need to see the result for each month number even if it is 0.

The query that I am running should give `13` on month number `3` and `0` on other months. But what is happening is the number `13` is divided and distributed into all 12 months like the following:

[image]

And here is the query:

```
SELECT 
    count(patients) as patients, month

FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        count(app_id) as patients, 
        month(date_app) as month 
    FROM 
        dentist.appointment
    WHERE id_logged=1 AND year(date_app)='2016'
    GROUP BY month(date_app)

    UNION SELECT 0,1
    UNION SELECT 0,2
    UNION SELECT 0,3
    UNION SELECT 0,4
    UNION SELECT 0,5
    UNION SELECT 0,6
    UNION SELECT 0,7
    UNION SELECT 0,8
    UNION SELECT 0,9
    UNION SELECT 0,10
    UNION SELECT 0,11
    UNION SELECT 0,12
) tmp
GROUP BY month
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
    count(app_id) as patients, 
    t.m as month 
FROM (    
   SELECT 1 AS m UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION
   SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION
   SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 10 UNION SELECT 11 UNION SELECT 12) AS t
LEFT JOIN dentist.appointment ON t.m = month(date_app) AND
          id_logged = 1 AND year(date_app) = 2016
GROUP BY t.m
```

The trick is first create an in-line table containing all 12 month numbers, *then* `LEFT JOIN` your original table to the in-line table.

**Note:** Predicates `id_logged = 1` and `year(date_app) = 2016` should be placed in the `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN` operation, otherwise `LEFT JOIN` becomes an `INNER JOIN`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35689/2)

Comment: nope, still getting only `patients: 13 || month: 3`

Comment: @androidnation Silly mistake. I should have place the predicates of the `WHERE` clause in `ON`. Check the edit I made.

Comment: Done. It is working now. Can you explain the query for me ?

Comment: The left join returns always all the records of the table on the left side. Hence a record for every month value is being returned. `count(app_id)` returns `0` if there is no match to the `appointment` table.